# curl not passing phpsessid

Tags: php, curl

Try as I might, I am unable to get curl to pass the `PHPSESSID` cookie.  I have a similar setup to what several others have described, but I haven't been able to get any of the proposed solutions working.

I have a page that sends a get request to `pageA.php`.  `pageA.php` needs some information from `pageB.php`, which is on another server, so I am using curl.  `pageB` maintains the session state that I need to get to and from my page.

I am able to pass other cookies from `pageA` to `pageB`, just not the `PHPSESSID` cookie.

The following works (a cookie arrives on `pageB`):
    `$options[CURLOPT_COOKIE] =  "myPHPSESSID=" . $sessionId;`

The following does not:

```
$options[CURLOPT_COOKIE] =  "PHPSESSID=" . $sessionId;
```

(I build an $options array and then pass it to `curl_set_opt_array`)

In fact, the latter causes some sort of error that I am unable to discern, as my call to `curl_exec` never returns (and `pageB` is never reached).

I've tried setting the header instead of using CURLOPT_COOKIE, but also with no success:

```
$options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER][] = "Cookie: myPHPSESSID=" . $sessionId;
```

the above works just fine but

```
$options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER][] = "Cookie: PHPSESSID=" . $sessionId;
```

does not.

PHP evidently does not want me to manually set PHPSESSID.  I'm not sure if it's relevant, but at no time on pageA do I call `start_session()` (though I tried doing so and had the same results).

I realize I could (probably) just pass the session id as a differently-named cookie and have pageB call `set_session_id()` or something similar.  But I really want to know why what I'm doing is not working, as I'd rather fix what I'm doing wrong than create a workaround.  I can provide some dumps of the various headers that are pinging around if that's helpful, but I figure this question is long enough for now.

Thanks...

Answer (score 11):

Call `session_write_close();` before your curl_exec.

This saved my life: http://kmak.1funkybit.com/?p=126 (read for explanation).

Example:

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION); //See what's in session
echo "<br>";



$c = curl_init('http://192.168.100.204/logintest/index.php?r=AccessTest/CheckAcess');
$parametros_post = 'action=verChau';
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametros_post);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
session_write_close();
$page = curl_exec ($c);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $page;
curl_close ($c);


?>
```

Comment: thanks, though I saw this advice and tried it to no avail.  My page never calls `start_session();`, so `session_write_close();` does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Hmmmm but where you get the $sessionID if you don't start any session? You can pass PHPSESSID with curl, because I am doing that with Yii and plain script. I've update my post with the script.

Comment: Oh - sorry to be unclear.  The `$sessionId` is coming from the client browser.  My php page that uses curl is just a proxy to get around cross-domain issues, so it doesn't maintain any session state.  I read `$sessionId` from `$_COOKIE` that accompanies each request from the client to the proxy page.

Comment: God! That was my problem... Thanks!